# A recommended JAX-WS framework for working with Moxy

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf, moxy

Currently I'm working with CXF but because of the following code in CXF:

```
// fall back if we're using another jaxb implementation
try {
 riContext = JAXBUtils.createRIContext(contextClasses
           .toArray(new Class[contextClasses.size()]), tns);
}
```

CXF loads both Moxy and the RI JAXB context (Probably depends on non standard APIs).
The overhead in startup time and memory is too high in my case.
I'm looking for a good open source JAX-WS implementation (CXF replacement) which will work with Moxy as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Metro implementation of JAX-WS (that GlassFish uses) can easily be configured to use MOXy as the JAXB provider.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/glassfish-312-is-full-of-moxy.html

In WebLogic as of version 12.1.1 MOXy is the default JAXB implementation (including the one used by JAX-WS).

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html

For any other JAX-WS implementation where MOXy can't be configured as the JAXB provider it can be used via the `Provider` mechanism:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/02/leveraging-moxy-in-your-web-service-via.html

Answer (score 4):

The 3.0.0-milestone2 version of CXF should handle Moxy quite a bit better.  That said, there are still bugs in Moxy that have prevented all of the CXF unit and system tests to pass with it so we don't have the same level of confidence with Moxy as we do with the JAXB RI.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, these are great news! 
Since I had a specific question on how to fix CXF issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630539/configure-cxf-jax-ws-service-to-work-with-moxy if you will copy your answer there I'll be happy to accept it as the answer. @Daniel Kulp